# Preparing SQLite SQL statements in PHP

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, escaping

I'm trying how best to prepare my SQLite SQL strings in PHP.  The SQLite3 class comes with an [escapeString()](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.escapestring.php) function, but here are my issues:

**Try 1)**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO items ('id','content','title','created') VALUES ('4e7ce7c18aac8', 'Does this work', NULL, '2011-09-23T16:10:41-04:00');";
$sql = SQLite3::escapeString( $sql );
echo ($sql);
```

This results in a string that's all jacked up:

> INSERT INTO items (''id'',''content'',''title'',''created'') VALUES
>   (''4e7ce7c18aac8'', ''Does this work'', NULL,
>   ''2011-09-23T16:10:41-04:00'');

Those aren't double quotes, rather doubled-up single quotes. Obviously won't work.

---

**Try 2)**

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO items ("id","content","title","created") VALUES ("4e7ce7c18aac8", "Does this work", NULL, "2011-09-23T16:10:41-04:00");';
$sql = SQLite3::escapeString( $sql );
echo ($sql);
```

This results in:

> INSERT INTO items ("id","content","title","created") VALUES
>   ("4e7ce7c18aac8", "Does this work", NULL,
>   "2011-09-23T16:10:41-04:00");

This query works fine, but the escapeString function hasn't modified anything as there's nothing to escape...

---

**Try 3)**

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO items ("id","content","title","created") VALUES ("4e7ce7c18aac8", "Doesn't this work", NULL, "2011-09-23T16:10:41-04:00");'; $sql = SQLite3::escapeString( $sql ); echo ($sql);
```

Here's the big problem- Now I have an apostrophe in one of my values.  It won't even make it to escapeString() because PHP will throw an error on the invalid string:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ','
>   or ';'

---

How am I supposed to be approaching this?  Keep in mind that in the actual code my parameter values will be variables, so am I supposed to escape each variable before I pass it into the string?  If so, what function do I use?

Finally, what's the point of escapeString()?? I can't figure out how it's supposed to be used correctly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't escape the entire query. You escape unsafe data you're inserting into the query, e.g.

```
$unsafe = $_GET['nastyvar'];
$safe = SQLite3::escapeString($unsafe);
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES ($safe);";
echo ($sql);
```

Comment: OK thanks Marc- but now the database stores the values with the escape slashes in them- when I read out, it shows like this: 
doesn\'t this work?
what about when I \"do\" this?    How do I unescape them for display again? Is there a standard way?

Comment: Nevermind think I found it: stripcslashes() to unescape.  Thanks--

Comment: Getting those extra slashes suggests that your PHP has magic_quotes enabled. Turn that off immediately.

Comment: can you elaborate some more on the magic_quotes issue (or point me to a resource).  My app will run on multiple systems, many which will have magic_quotes on- does that matter?

Comment: http://php.net/magic_quotes   it's a deprecated (and outright moronic to begin with) feature, and if you're running on systems with it turned on, they're badly configured and/or running obsolete versions of PHP.